# [iOS]How to cover status bar like Facebook Paper？

Tags: ios, statusbar

Facebook Paper uses a card-style view controller. The background has a status bar, which can be covered by the front card.

How to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `-prefersStatusBarHidden` ? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prefersStatusBarHidden

Comment: @timominous actually, the status bar is not hidden. it just being covered by the top view controller(or view). You can see in the screenshot i gave, there is a half of the status bar being shown. if you use **-prefersStatusBarHidden**, the whole status bar will be hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically a new `UIWindow` that has higher `windowLevel`.
You make a new window and set `windowLevel` to something like `UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1`. Then, the content of the window will float on top of the status bar.

But beware! Apple AppStore does not like "abusing status bar", and will reject whatever if they feel you're abusing status bar stuffs. This is just another story from how you can implement.

If you're looking for a tutorial, here's nice one.

http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/02/07/how-to-build-the-facebook-paper-status-bar-hover/